# <button> not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple buttons with different functionality, but each button behaves as submit button. I want to give different behavior for each of the button created.

```
<form action="/createUpdate">
<!--here i have form elements like textbox , checkboxes etc --!>
       <button name="buttonName" id="submitButton1" value="create">create</button> 
       <button name="buttonName" id="submitButton2" value="Update">Update</button>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the buttons to input type=submit, only the pressed button will be sent.

For example:

```
<form action="/createUpdate">
<!--here i have form elements like textbox , checkboxes etc -->
       <input type="submit" name="buttonName" id="submitButton1" value="create" />
       <input type="submit" name="buttonName" id="submitButton2" value="Update" />
</form>
```